# Database configuration in zend framework

Tags: apache, zend-framework

I am getting error when something is related to database connection in zend framework. The server is unix server running apache.

Here is my application.ini configuration

`resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"`

`resources.db.params.host = "localhost"`

`resources.db.params.username = "a5633138_hotel"`

`resources.db.params.password = "passowrd"`

`resources.db.params.dbname = "a5633138_hotel"`

`resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true`

Do I need to configure something else if it is live server for example is it ok if I write localhost in host part.

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: log in /home/a5633138/public_html/application/controllers/ErrorController.php on line 33` and `Fatal error: Call to a member function log() on a non-object in /home/a5633138/public_html/application/controllers/ErrorController.php on line 34`

Comment: But this happens only in those pages where it needs to connect to database.

Comment: It will happen in all cases wherever exception is thrown . Comment line 34 or post the code here.

Comment: Actually, this is working well in local server. I know that this will come out whenever exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your ErrorController.php with following contents

```
<?php

class ErrorController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function errorAction()
    {
        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
        $errors = $this->_getParam('error_handler');

        if (!$errors || !$errors instanceof ArrayObject) {
            $this->view->message = 'You have reached the error page';
            return;
        }

        switch ($errors->type) {
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE:
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER:
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION:
                // 404 error -- controller or action not found
                $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);
                $priority = Zend_Log::NOTICE;
                $this->view->message = 'Page not found';
                break;
            default:
                // application error
                $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(500);
                $priority = Zend_Log::CRIT;
                $this->view->message = 'Application error';
                break;
        }

        // Log exception, if logger available
        $log = $this->getLog();
        if ($log) {
            $log->log($this->view->message, $priority, $errors->exception);
            $log->log('Request Parameters', $priority, $errors->request->getParams());
        }

        // conditionally display exceptions
        if ($this->getInvokeArg('displayExceptions') == true) {
            $this->view->exception = $errors->exception;
        }

        $this->view->request   = $errors->request;
    }

    public function getLog()
    {
        $bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
        if (!$bootstrap->hasResource('Log')) {
            return false;
        }
        $log = $bootstrap->getResource('Log');
        return $log;
    }


}
```

Comment: Yes, I got it, `Message: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'a5633138_hotel'@'localhost' (using password: YES) `

Comment: But the problem is I am using the same login and password is ok in phpmyadmin, this is funny;

Comment: @AkramYakubov I find spelling of password incorrect 'passowrd' may be its intentional .

Comment: Other reason could be your phpmyadmin is running locally on same DB server and you are making a remote connection to DB server . For which extra privileges needs to be given to same user.

Comment: Actually, I am running it on the free hosting. so it has some restriction, let create another db and try

Comment: Finally, I solved the problem, the issue was host. I mentioned I put localhost, but actually the working host is `mysql8.000webhost.com`